# Audit truncate and drop

Tags: oracle, truncate, audit

I want to capture truncate and drop statements on one table.

In some google searches i got that it's impossible to execute:

```
audit truncate, drop on schema.table;
```

So I tried:

```
audit table;
```

As I understand, this supposed to capture create, drop and truncate about all the tables.

So, my questions:

1. Is that realy the best way to do it? I want only on one specific table.
2. Even with that statement - after I execute a truncate on table, it's not captured.

> DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL

stay with no data..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can audit DROP TABLE and TRUNCATE TABLE on a specific table.

Here is my audit_trail parameter and it's value.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest              string  /u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adu
                         mp
audit_sys_operations             boolean     TRUE
audit_syslog_level           string
audit_trail              string  DB, EXTENDED
unified_audit_sga_queue_size         integer     1048576
```

I have created table table called tbl1.

```
SQL> conn jay
Password:

Connected.
SQL> create table tbl1(id number);

Table created.
```

Now, let's enable auditing on that table. If you specify `ALL` on a table then oracle will audit `CREATE TABLE`, `DROP TABLE` and `TRUNCATE TABLE` operations. Specify `BY ACCESS` if you want oracle to write one record for each audited statement and operation.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
SQL> audit all on jay.tbl1 by access; -- or  just audit all on jay.tbl1

Audit succeeded.
```

Create new session using Jay user and perform some operations.

```
SQL> conn jay

SQL> truncate table tbl1; 

Table truncated.

SQL> drop table tbl1;

Table dropped.
```

Let's check the audit trail.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba

SQL> select action_name from dba_audit_trail where obj_name='TBL1';

ACTION_NAME
----------------------------
DROP TABLE
TRUNCATE Table
```

Comment: Thanks. But it isn't worked for me... i created table in user A. Then I execute audit all on it. And then execute commands.. Select, insert and so on has written in dba_audit_trail. But the truncate just dont..

Comment: Finally, i do it with audit table by my_user; thanks!

Comment: I tested above code on Oracle 12.2, which worked perfectly as shown in the answer. I think you were using different versions.

Comment: Maybe. I'm using oralce 11g.